# Is it required to have ssl in my website to integrate Social media login

Tags: php, authentication, ssl

Is it required to have ssl in my website to integrate Facebook and Google login.

I integrated google login into my site without ssl and now get the error

> Error in retrieving token: "redirect_uri_mismatch"

Before this was working fine. But now its throwing above error.

Comment: you are using 2 different url in APP setting and URL

Comment: @devpro, When url was different then the error was different check bellow
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://example.com/site/login?service=google_oauth, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized r

Comment: than you must need to share code here

Comment: I am using the library https://github.com/Nodge/yii2-eauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#https

> Use HTTPS, instead of HTTP, as an internet protocol, because it uses encryption. HTTPS keeps transmitted data private and guards against eavesdropping attacks. It also prevents data from being tampered with during transmission by, for example, introducing advertisements or malicious code.
>
> **On October 6, 2018, all apps will be required to use HTTPS.**

I believe all *new* Facebook apps are already required to use HTTPS, but either way you'll need it in the next couple of weeks anyways. Now that SSL is free and easy via things like Let's Encrypt, CloudFlare, etc., there's really no excuse for not having SSL set up - it's safer for everyone involved.

I'm not sure on Google's policies on this - I'd expect them to require HTTPS soon if they aren't already. If they don't strictly require it yet, make sure your "Authorized Redirect URIs" field in the Google Developer Console includes the HTTP version.

**TL;DR:** Get HTTPS in place.